# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '' is not a valid attribute name

Tags: angular

My Angular application build is successful, but when I open it in browser, it is blank and below error is coming in browser console. Not able to find the problem

```
core.mjs:6469 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '' is not a valid attribute name.

Error: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '' is not a valid attribute name.

    at DefaultDomRenderer2.setAttribute (platform-browser.mjs:599)
    at BaseAnimationRenderer.setAttribute (animations.mjs:273)
    at setUpAttributes (core.mjs:2830)
    at Module.ɵɵelementStart (core.mjs:14499)
    at NavigationComponent_Template (navigation.component.html:73)
    at executeTemplate (core.mjs:9603)
    at renderView (core.mjs:9406)
    at renderComponent$1 (core.mjs:10687)
    at renderChildComponents (core.mjs:9271)
    at renderView (core.mjs:9431)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1255)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1209)
    at zone.js:1321
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:434)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25437)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:433)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:205)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:620)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.mjs:6469
index.js:548 [webpack-dev-server] Live Reloading enabled.
```

Comment: We need some context here.

Comment: Can you please add code to which file have you got the issue?

Comment: Looking at the error it seems that somewhere in your code, you are calling `setAttribute` method by passing an empty string as the 1st parameter. Code snippet will provide some context.

Comment: I am not able to find the file in which this error is coming.ng build does not throw any error. When i open app in browser it throw this error. Any suggestion how to trace it.

Comment: How does the line 73 of navigation.component.html look like?

Comment: I have compared all my changes since last check-in to find this.  You quickly identified Lukasz. Thanks a lot for quick help